# With same nodejs version and yarn.lock, install frozen-lockfile works on Ubuntu but fail on Mac

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

This is my understanding of how `yarn` nodejs package management works

- `yarn.lock` declares the exact version of packages installed on your project. This list of package is **independent** of OS.
- Criteria affect what specific will be added into the `yarn.lock` file include:

  - current node version
  - `package.json` file

-> Current OS doesn't affect what package is put inside `yarn.lock` when you run `yarn install`

What I did:

- run `yarn install` on Ubuntu 14.04 -> generates `yarn.lock`
- copy this `yarn.lock` onto a Mac machine
- USE THE SAME `nodejs` version as the one on Ubuntu 14.04, run `yarn install --frozen-lockfile`

And the the installation fails. But when I use a different version of `nodejs` on Mac, running `yarn install --frozen-lockfile` works.

So does this mean with:

- Same `yarn.lock` file
- Same `nodejs`

one CAN'T GUARANTEED the installation would work across all OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `yarn.lock` it won't work 100% on other platforms until unless all dependencies support cross platforms

Just checked my `yarn.lock` they add some dependencies based on an operating system in my case it was `is-windows` module added

Check all your packages are supported for cross platforms because sometimes many packages are platform specific, You can check all dependencies on packages.json of that package

OR

Do not push `yarn.lock` if you use the application on different operating systems.

Comment: Thanks. A side question if you don't mind: if I develop on MacOS and deploy on Ubuntu and use native library, how do I make sure package versions are the same on my laptop and the production environment without `yarn.lock` file?

Comment: Mac and Linux won't have much difference since both UNIX. Whenever you choose packages from NPM repository make sure that which is not hat you specific to any platform and about version issue do not allow package. json to auto update, . If you too strict about version

Comment: Or Docker is what you are looking for

Comment: I too thought that Docker is the answer.